# How to convert numbers to other numbers with a function from a csv file

Tags: python, function

I have 2 column .csv file with contains numbers like:

20 12 24.2312, 12 12 23.312

12 15 26.123, 52 12 12.772

...

...

etc.

I want to convert these values with a function

```
data=pd.read_csv("test2.csv")

def deg(s): #takes H:M:S, returns S
  c = str(s).split()
  # 0: hour, 1: min, 2: sec
  v = float(c[0]) + float(c[1])/60 + float(c[2])/3600 #convert all to H
  return v*15 #convert to rad"""

for obj in range(len(data)):
    rss=(deg(obj[0]),deg(obj[1]))
    degres.append(rss)
```

However i get "'int' object is not subscriptable" error. How can i do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First as you shown data does not contain any header, you should say it to `read_csv`:

```
data=pd.read_csv("test2.csv", header=None)
```

Next as you want to apply the same scalar function to all the cells of your dataframe, a simple way is to tranform it column by column with pandas methods:

```
result = data.transform(lambda s: s.transform(deg))
```

From your example data, it gives

```
            0           1
0  303.100963  183.097133
1  183.858846  783.053217
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case obj is actually an integer: 0, 1, ....
To get access to the numbers from the cells you have to do like this.

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv("test2.csv", header = None)
print(data)

def deg(s): #takes H:M:S, returns S
  c = str(s).split()
  # 0: hour, 1: min, 2: sec
  v = float(c[0]) + float(c[1])/60 + float(c[2])/3600 #convert all to H
  return v*15 #convert to rad"""

degres = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    obj = data[i]
    rss=(deg(obj[0]),deg(obj[1]))
    degres.append(rss)

print(degres)
```

Most likely there are other ways to write it in a more pandas/dataframe style.